# Treesort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, tree

I have this sorting algorithm which constructs an (unbalanced) tree and performs in-order traversal in order to sort the requested range. However, the more order exists in the input array, the closer to time complexity of \$\Theta(n^2)\$ it will get, yet it runs in \$\Theta(n \log n)\$ on most randomly generated arrays.

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class holds some static sorting methods.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class CoderoddeArrays {

    /**
     * This class represents an unbalanced binary search tree. Provides only
     * minimum functionality needed in Treesort algorithm. It performs well
     * on randomly generated data, but may degrade to a quadratic time sort on
     * arrays with lots of pre-existing order. (On ascending/descending array it
     * will degrade to quadratic time.)
     *
     * @param <E> the element type.
     */
    private static class Tree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
    implements Iterable<E> {

        static class Node<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

            E value;
            Node<E> left;
            Node<E> right;
            Node<E> parent;

            Node(final E value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        private Node<E> root;
        private int size;

        /**
         * Inserts a value into this <code>Tree</code>.
         *
         * @param value the value to insert.
         */
        void insert(final E value) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(value);

            if (root == null) {
                size = 1;
                root = newNode;
                return;
            }

            Node<E> parent = null;
            Node<E> current = root;
            int cmp = 0;

            while (current != null) {
                parent = current;
                current = (cmp = value.compareTo(current.value)) < 0 ?
                          current.left :
                          current.right;
            }

            if (cmp < 0) {
                parent.left = newNode;
            } else {
                parent.right = newNode;
            }

            newNode.parent = parent;
            size++;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the successor node of <code>node</code>.
         *
         * @param node the node whose successor to search.
         *
         * @return the successor node of <code>node</code> or <code>null</code>
         * if <code>node</code> is the rightmost node, i.e., has no successor.
         */
        Node<E> successor(Node<E> node) {
            if (node.right == null) {
                while (node.parent != null && node.parent.right == node) {
                    node = node.parent;
                }

                if (node.parent == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return node.parent;
                }
            }

            node = node.right;

            while (node.left != null) {
                node = node.left;
            }

            return node;
        }

        /**
         * Gets a tree iterator for this <code>Tree</code>.
         *
         * @return a tree iterator.
         */
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return new TreeIterator();
        }

        /**
         * This class traverses a <code>Tree</code> in-order.
         */
        public class TreeIterator implements Iterator<E> {

            private int retrieved;
            private Node<E> current;

            public TreeIterator() {
                current = root;

                // Go point to the least value node.
                if (current != null) {
                    while (current.left != null) {
                        current = current.left;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return retrieved < size;
            }

            @Override
            public E next() {
                if (retrieved == 0) {
                    retrieved = 1;
                    return current.value;
                }

                Node<E> node = successor(current);
                current = node;
                retrieved++;
                return current.value;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Sorts by means of constructing (an unbalanced) binary tree and traverses
     * it in-order.
     *
     * @param <E>       the element type; should be <code>Comparable</code>.
     * @param array     the array whose values to put in order.
     * @param fromIndex the staring index of the range to sort.
     * @param toIndex   the (exclusive) ending index of the range to sort.
     */
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
    void sort(final E[] array, 
              final int fromIndex, 
              final int toIndex) {
        Tree<E> tree = new Tree<>();

        // Load the tree.
        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            tree.insert(array[i]);
        }

        int index = fromIndex;

        // In-order traversal.
        for (final E element : tree) {
            array[index++] = element;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the entire array using Treesort algorithm.
     * 
     * @param <E>   the element type.
     * @param array the array to sort.
     */
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
    void sort(final E[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    private static final int LENGTH = 150000;
    private static final int MINIMUM = 300000;
    private static final int MAXIMUM = 500000;

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final Integer[] array1 = getRandomArray(LENGTH,
                                                MINIMUM,
                                                MAXIMUM,
                                                new Random(seed));
        final Integer[] array2 = array1.clone();

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(array1, 10, array1.length - 10);
        long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Arrays.sort() in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        sort(array2, 10, array2.length - 10);
        tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Treesort in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        // Strongly means "equal by references". I need this in order to be
        // able to assert that Treesort sorts stabily.
        System.out.println("Strongly equal: " + stronglyEquals(array1, array2));
    }

    private static Integer[] getRandomArray(final int length,
                                            final int minimum,
                                            final int maximum,
                                            final Random rnd) {
        final Integer[] array = new Integer[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            array[i] = rnd.nextInt(maximum - minimum + 1) + minimum;
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static <E> boolean stronglyEquals(final E[] array1,
                                              final E[] array2) {
        if (array1.length != array2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
            if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So as always, I am interested in all suggestions out there regarding naming, commenting, formatting, algorithm, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts:

```
    void insert(final E value) {
        (...)
        while (current != null) {
            parent = current;
            current = (cmp = value.compareTo(current.value)) < 0 ?
                      current.left :
                      current.right;
        }
```

Cmp assignment should prpbably be extracted from there - this causes the ternary to be less than immediately obvious

```
    Node<E> successor(Node<E> node) {
        if (node.right == null) {
            (...)
            if (node.parent == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return node.parent;
            }
        }
```

This if is a perfect candidate for a ternary:
`return node.parent == null ? null : node.parent;`

```
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }
```

you are using blocks similar to this quite a few times - consider adding a convenience method, something like this:

```
Node.getLeftMost(){
   return node.left!=null?node.left.getLeftMost():this;
}
```

Also:

```
public class TreeIterator implements Iterator<E> {
```

I don't think this class should be public - creating a TreeIterator object not related to an actual Tree does not make much sense

That's all I've found.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, cptBartender. Thanks for the answer, but would you mind isolating your comments/suggestions from your code? I wouldn't want anyone to think this is just a code dump.

Comment: Done - looks much more readable now.